# iOS Enterprise Developer Program

Tags: ios

For some reason I am not able to find this information anywhere.

1. How many developers can be added as part of the Enterprise Developer Program?
2. Are developers part of the Enterprise Developer Program allowed publish apps on the App Store?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. I'm not aware that there is a limit on the number of developers that can be added to a team
2. I think you would also need a non-enterprise membership if you also want to publish to the App Store

Comment: So what should a company choose for its employees if they want to offer in house development as well as app store development.

Comment: @azamsharp Choose both? Have an enterprise account for deploying locally and a normal account for app store sales.