# Is there any limitation to distribution of apps in iOS enterprise program?

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I know in iOS developer program, a developer can use an ad hoc distribution profile to build an app, and this app is for testing purpose and can be installed on up to 100 devices.

Is there such a limitation for app developed with a Enterprise program account?
And since this app is for internal use, does the employee's device need to be configured somehow to use this in-house app?

And is there any technical problem if I distribute the in-house app (for free) to a larger audience via a web link or email? I know this can be interpreted as violation to the Enterprise program, I am just wondering if this is technically doable.

Comment: Your contract with Apple says that the app can be used in house and in house only. If you work for the US Post Office, you can distribute it to their million employees. If your company has two employees, you are limited to a copy for one employee each. You are legally responsible for enforcing this, and I can see Apple getting _very_ angry if you intentionally violate this.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is no limitation on how many devices you can install the enterprise app. All you need is properly configured provisioning profile and signing identity and the UDID in the provisioning profile. I do believe you can distribute ad-hoc similarly as with normal iOS developer account, even easier.

There is much information available on **StackOverflow** already:

- [IOS Enterprise Distribution Through OTA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8439127/ios-enterprise-distribution-through-ota)
- [Enterprise distribution of iOS applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10936811/enterprise-distribution-of-ios-applications)
- [iOS Developer Enterprise Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11825686/ios-developer-enterprise-program)
- [iOS Enterprise Deployment / Expiration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18768895/ios-enterprise-deployment-expiration)
- [iOS enterprise account for distribution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16889675/ios-enterprise-account-for-distribution)
- [iOS Enterprise Developer Program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8213870/ios-enterprise-developer-program)
- [Deploying ios apps wirelessly .Enterprise apps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13458650/deploying-ios-apps-wirelessly-enterprise-apps)

And many more: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ios+enterprise

Please read through those first and you will get most of the information you need.

Comment: I don't think you need to know UDIDs for enterprise distribution.

Comment: Enterprise distribution does NOT require individual device UDIDs. I've used Enterprise distributions several times and that's one of the biggest benefits. Of course, see the answer below about "Untrusted Enterprise Developer".

Comment: @ericWasTaken Is it mentioned in apple documents? I know it's not needed, but my employee does not believe me hence will not pay for the account.

Comment: @farzadshbfn - here is the link to the Apple doc about Enterprise Apps. There's no mention of Device ID anywhere!! (So it's clearly not needed). https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps/DistributingEnterpriseProgramApps.html

Comment: @ericWasTaken Thanks, I think he's trying to avoid me, because I already sent him this doc, he won't buy it :))). tnx

Comment: I could not find any apple's doc about device limitation for enterprise account. Can anyone please share apple's official link that have clarification of device limitation.

Answer (score 8):

Beginning iOS 9, another important consideration is on first install Apple prompts you with an 'Untrusted Enterprise Developer' prompt. This requires you to go to Settings: General > Profiles and select 'Trust X' for the correct profile.

Not a show stopper. However, an important consideration if you need to do a large distribution as testers need to be informed.

[image]

Comment: And there is no indication to the users on where to go and Trust it, the error message should ideally have a button to take the users to the settings, some of my users got annoyed :)

Comment: Do we need to add UDID still ?

Comment: @HituBansal nope, no UDIDs with Enterprise Profile. Installs on any device.