# iOS package for iPad freezes while installing in device

Tags: ios, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova, apache-cordova

I have developed an app targeting windows and iOS. The windows build works perfectly while installing on device but not the iOS app.

I am using a Visual Studio 2015 on my windows 8.1 PC and have a MAC connected remotely. I have specified iOS version 9.0 in config.xml file. It successfully creates release builds for iOS by generating a .ipa file.

When I put this file in my mac system, connect my iPad air with version 9.02 and try to install the app on device with itunes, the status says installing but then freezes. It never completes installing the app completely.

FYI- The provisioning file I have used for it is an AD-HOC provisioning file. My device along with its UDID is registered in my apple developer account too.

What are the probable reasons for it? How can I correct it?

Comment: Hi, could you please use libimobiledevice to see what errors it reports?

Comment: You can install libimobiledevice by 1:Install homebrew following instructions from [http://brew.sh/](http://brew.sh/).
2.run  “brew install ideviceinstaller libimobiledevice”
3. run “ideviceinstaller -i path/to/package.ipa”

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install release build with itunes. Use debug build, and it will work.

Comment: Are you Sure about it? Currently I am not at my workplace so that I can check it but need to update my seniors tomorrow?

Comment: The main thing is can I send a debug build to various people to check on their iPads? I mean will it work from them?

Comment: Sorry for these many questions but I dont have an option! Thank you for your answer. The debug build worked.  Now the main question which arises is that as my application is a big one with many modules and pages, after the completion of the project, What will be the kind of build I will be generating? This app will be used by hundreds of people. Will I have to generate debug build for them at the end??

Comment: Sorry for delay. Since I am not apple developer, I can't answer all questions. I'll try some of them. To be able install app in "Debug" mode on device, you need development provisioning profile, with device you are going to install on it, included. The limit for devices you can add - 100. So, if you are need more than this, you need another solution. Again, I am not apple developer, so I can't help you much here. I think here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22745946/is-there-any-limitation-to-distribution-of-apps-in-ios-enterprise-program, you'll find the answer.